# Create a Dialog from AlarmManager?

Tags: android

I have scheduled an alarm using the AlarmManager and it fires off a BroadcastReceiver.  Inside the broadcast receiver I want to call an Activity and create a popup dialog.

The important thing here is I want to see the background of wherever the user is and NOT bring my application to the front first.  Take a look at the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Now here is what happens, which I do not want:
1. User is looking at my application
2. User presses home and is now in some other application
3. My application is still running in the background
4. Alarm triggers->BroadcastReceiver->The above intent is started
5. The user is now looking at the last page of MY application and my popup dialog

What I want instead is:
5. The user is still looking at whatever application they were in, but they now have my popup dialog.

How can I call the activity without bringing my application to the front?

Comment: A popup appearing from nowhere is bad for the user experience. You should use a notification instead.

Comment: That is a totally different scenario in my app.  If the user picks to be alarmed, then I think a popup notification along with sound/vibrate would be appropriate, just like the built in Alarm application.  Maybe I can look at the source to see how the Alarm application handles it?

Comment: You can't start a dialog from a `BroadcastReceiver`. You could have an activity with a dialog theme that you start instead( in the `BroadcastReceiver`), so you have the appearance of a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

What Luksprog said is true, but even the default alarm shows an AlertDialog when the time corresponds to your alarm settings.
You can put this code into your other code that does what it does when your alarm(s) starts:

```
    public void alertBtn1 (View v){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("AlertDialog")
            .setMessage(R.string.text OR "YOURTEXTHERE")
    // If you want to the user to have multiple options, you can replace this
            .setNeutralButton("YOURTEXTHERE", null)
    // with this:               
            .setNeutralButton("YOURTEXTHERE", null)
            .setPositiveButton("YOURTEXTHERE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // finish(); or whatever you like to happen when the user clicks the button.
                    finish();
                    }
                })
            .show();

    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to start an activity in order to do that?  You can see in my above steps where I do launch an activity show I can show an AlertDialog.  The problem is it bring up whatever last page my application was on.  How do I keep the application from coming to the front?

Comment: Hmm... then I am not sure how I can help you because I honestly don't know. Try and experiment with your code. You could refer to another class that has the code that pops up the AlertDialog and have the original class/activity activate it. This way, your last page that you were on in your application won't be brought forward. Also, you could use finish(); to terminate the page and bring you back to the last page you were on.